# PhpStorm PhpUnit via phar autocomplete not working

Tags: autocomplete, phpunit, phpstorm

I have PHPStorm 8.0.1.

PHPUnit is installed via PHAR archive like:

```
wget https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x phpunit.phar
sudo mv phpunit.phar /usr/bin/phpunit
```

PHPUnit works via cli:

```
user@pc:/usr/bin$ cd ~
user@pc:~$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 4.3.5 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

I followed the instructions from JetBrains website https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/enabling-phpunit-support.html#d298258e897

In PHPStorm File->Settings tab PHP/PHPUnit
the radio button `Path to phpunit.phar` is checked
and value is set to `/usr/bin/phpunit`

I have a file with a test defined like:

```
class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
...
```

At this point PHPStorm marks `Undefined class PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`

I've restarted PHPStorm and Computer, but still have the same problem.

I've also tried adding `/usr/bin` to include path (right click on external libraries in project view, and choose option `Configure PHP include paths`) without success.

Here's the config for PHPStorm Settings, tab PHP (if it matters):

```
PHP Language level: 5.5 (finally, generators, etc.)
Interpreter: PHP 5.5 (5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5)
Include path is empty
```

Comment: If it's a PHAR file then it should have `.phar` extension -- that's a requirement, unfortunately. Just place `phpunit.phar` anywhere in your project -- it will be enough for IDE to index it.

Comment: Is there a way not to include that file in the project, and somehow read it from another location (with phar extension)?

Comment: Use symbolic link. Or place a copy (or symbolic link) in separate folder and reference that folder via "Include Paths" functionality

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I symlinked /usr/bin/phpunit to ~/phpUnitReference/phpunit.phar, and then added that dir to include path, and now it works. I was under the impression that PHPStorm has a way of referencing phpUnit automatically, but this works also. Thanks again. Would you like to make an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In order to have a PHAR archive indexed by the IDE it has to have a `.phar` extension (that's a requirement).

The easiest solution is to place `phpunit.phar` somewhere in your project (usually it would be `PROJECT_ROOT/vendor/` folder).

If having local copy inside the project folder is not desired (for whatever reason; although Composer and other similar kind of tools (bower/npm/etc) are primarily aimed at keeping dependency stuff/packages locally), you may use **symbolic links**:

- either create a symbolic link to that file locally (e.g. `PROJECT_ROOT/phpunit.phar` --> `/usr/bin/phpunit`)
- or place a full copy (or such symbolic link) in a *separate folder outside of the project* and then reference it via PhpStorm's `Settings | PHP | Include Paths` functionality.

Comment: This seems to be the solution, however for me it didn't work, probably because of a bug in PhpStorm. What I did to fix it is right click on the .phar and clicked "Exclude phar from project", then clicked again "Include phar into project".

Comment: This worked for me. I created a symlink of phpunit into vendor/ dir and excluded it from git in .gitignore and as soon as I created the link phpstorm started indexing it's contents. 

ln -s /usr/local/bin/phpunit phpunit.phar

Answer (score 0):

The above fix by [Calin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1104534/calin) worked for me too on PhpStorm 2019.1.1, so I'll post it as an answer for easier visibility:

Try right clicking on the .phar and clicking **"Exclude phar from project"**, then clicking **"Include phar into project"** to refresh it.

In my case, both the `.phar` file and my `.idea` folder were pulled from a git commit. I guess PhpStorm didnt realise that the file needed reimporting.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed even though PHP itself can find and run phar that is in its include path, PHPStorm having trouble finding and parsing them.

LazyOne's explanation is correct, however, I didn't need to put it in project folder to be recognized, you can put them in any path as long as its path is introduced to IDE. In my case, I put all phar files in PHP folder, so I just needed to add PHP folder to `Include Path` list in IDE

`Include Path` for PHP is under `Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP` screen (that tiny `+` at the bottom of screen).