# How to use the phpUnit autocompletion in IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, phpunit

I create some phpUnit tests in Intellij IDEA but I can not use the autocompletion of my IDE.

I use the `phpunit-5.5.5.phar`
The test class extends from `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`, but the autocompletion does not work but the functionality from phpUnit works.

Where is the mistake of my configuration?

[image: Config]

[image: phpUnit Image]

Comment: Can you also show your project structure?

Comment: This question might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27245118/phpstorm-phpunit-via-phar-autocomplete-not-working

Comment: @Katie Thank you, your link contains the solution. Settings | PHP | Include Paths